Spring Cloud Gateway - How to implement Rate Limiter not by Key, but by Class of User - or should I use AWS API Gateway?
I'm currently trying to implement a Rate Limiter on my AWS infrastructure.
Requests for my app currently go through Spring Cloud Gateway (which does circuit breaking, retries, rate limiting, and a timeout)
My rate limiter code looks like this:
@Configuration
internal class RequestRateLimiterConfig(
    private val requestRateLimiterGatewayFilterFactory: RequestRateLimiterGatewayFilterFactory,
    private val redisRateLimiter: RedisRateLimiter,
    private val defaultKeyResolver: KeyResolver
) {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestRateLimiterConfig::class.java)

    @Bean
    fun requestRateLimiter(): GlobalFilter {

        // rate limiter filter
        val rateLimiterConfig = RequestRateLimiterGatewayFilterFactory.Config().apply {
            rateLimiter = redisRateLimiter
            keyResolver = defaultKeyResolver
            denyEmptyKey = true
            statusCode = HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS
            emptyKeyStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.name
        }

        val rateLimiterFilter = requestRateLimiterGatewayFilterFactory.apply(rateLimiterConfig)

        return GlobalFilter { exchange, chain ->
            val keyMono = defaultKeyResolver.resolve(exchange)
            keyMono
                .flatMap { key ->
                    if (key.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        // if key is null or empty, return error
                        logger.warn("Empty session ID detected. Sending error response.")
                        return@flatMap LocalExceptionHandlers.missingKey(exchange)
                    } else {
                        // if key is present, continue with rate limiting
                        logger.info("Resolved key: $key")
                        return@flatMap rateLimiterFilter.filter(exchange, chain)
                            .onErrorResume { e ->
                                // Handle rate limiting errors and send error response
                                val status = exchange.response.statusCode
                                if (status == HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS) {
                                    return@onErrorResume LocalExceptionHandlers.rateLimitExceeded(exchange)
                                }
                                Mono.error(e)
                            }
                    }
                }.then()
        }
    }
}

    /**
     * Redis Rate Limited
     */
    @Bean
    fun redisRateLimiter(): RedisRateLimiter {
        return RedisRateLimiter(10, 20, 1)
    }

    /**
     * Default Key Resolver
     */
    @Bean
    fun defaultKeyResolver(): KeyResolver {
        return KeyResolver { exchange: ServerWebExchange ->
            val sessionId = exchange.request.cookies[sessionProperties.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME]?.first()?.value
            if (sessionId.isNullOrBlank()) {
                logger.warn("No session ID found in cookie.")
                Mono.just("")
            } else {
                logger.info("Resolved session ID for Rate Limiting: $sessionId")
                Mono.justOrEmpty(sessionId)
            }
        }
    }


It is fairly simple with rate limiting done by a key present in the request (in my case session cookie id)
Now, what if I wanted to have different rate limits, by "classes of users" e.g. (premium, basic, admin_user, normal_user)
How would I do that using SCG? I tried exploring AWS API Gateway as they have something called Usage Plans for Rate limiting, but it didn't make sense having two Gateways, AWS API Gateway + Spring Cloud Gateway.
My SCG does do authorization, so does get an access token from Auth0 by Okta, and store that in redis.
In theory, like API Gateway has a Lambda Authorizer, I could verify the token in the SCG, to get e.g. the ROLE of a user, and based on that use different rate limiters.
But I have been told that verifying an access token in both the SCG, and Spring Rest API behind it, is bad practice. (currently the access token sent by the SCG app is verified by the Spring Rest API only (using Spring Security Resource Server. SCG uses Spring Security Client, to get the access token only from Auth0 by Okta)
Or should I just try to use AWS API Gateway?
Any help to the above would be appreciated

You seem to be implementing an access control rule to resources and, to me, that should stand on resource servers. For instance, I'm not sure you'll want the same limits for all resources. If you implement this rate-limit access control on the resource server, you should have all the context you need about the user.

That definitely makes sense - it is an access control rule based on the user, rather than a blanket rule for all users. As you suggest, I could have spring cloud gateway, in both my spring bff, and spring resource server. The spring bff, can do authorization, retry mechanism, circuit breaking, and time out limiting (blanket rules), and the spring resource server can serve resources, and do rate limiting. It would mean configuring the resource server to also access redis (as the rate limiter is backed by redis - and using a different key for the rate limiter - not the session cookie id)

If the key is the session ID, the rate limitation is applied per user agent instance (you might even have different sessions in different "private navigation" tabs). So you probably want a key based on the user subject anyway.
